# How do I do COM Interop in Java?

Tags: java, com, ms-office, com-interop

I am a .NET programmer working with a Java Spring Boot project to create a REST API. I need to do some COM interop with an Excel spreadsheet from within the Spring Boot application.

How do I go about doing that?

I know the code to write. I just don't know the tools. Specifically, what jar files do I need to reference? Where do I get them from?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would prefer

https://poi.apache.org/

Otherwise you can use "Java Access Bridge", here is an overview

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/access/jab/introduction.html#jab-overview

Comment: Here is an example for the apache poi https://www.mkyong.com/java/apache-poi-reading-and-writing-excel-file-in-java/

Comment: Thanks very much. I will explore. Both seem a little verbose as compared to interop using C# or even a third-party such as Aspose. I will give them a try.