# Is it possible to listen to an event in MS Word in java?

Tags: java, events, ms-word, com, jacob

I'm making an application when an user can modify the content of a MS Word document and when the user clicks the saving button, the file will be send to the server.

So I just wanted to known if it's possible with JACOB or any other COM wrapper using Java, to listen to events in Word ? If so, could you tell me how ? I look through the web and I couldn't find any solution. Thanks in advance !

Comment: These articles will be helpful.[Java, Jacob and Microsoft Word: how to properly handle events?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24639627/9014308), [Java, Jacob and Microsoft Outlook events: Receiving “Can't find event iid” Error](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3052963/9014308), [How do I do COM Interop in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45729786/9014308), [Java connection to / between Microsoft Windows Office Suite?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/396448/9014308)

Answer (score -1):

So I don't know if Java would be best language of choice. I found something that indicates that the save event it not explicitly exposed, but there is an event just prior to the save. However, this might have to be coded in C# or Visual Basic. You might be able to use the VB event to trigger java code, that when the file is updated (date modified or something) then it uploads to the sever.

Here is the MSDN page that might help with the save listener, Hope it Helps. Good luck.

[Listening to Save event in word.](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/5fe38b3f-4bdf-4cc5-b7aa-8f0409e09153/microsoftofficeinteropword-listening-to-a-documents-save-and-close-event?forum=vsto)